# keyPressEvent on QDialog using IPython

Tags: python

When Escape Key was pressed, QDialog will hide automatically. How to use keypressEvent for QDialog using IPython?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackexchange. It will be easier to give an answer if you outline previous research, show some code examples and describe your use-case.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn  
The Below mentioned KeyPressEvent function was taken from a website. But I don't how to connect a QDialog with that function (Signal name and arguments to be passed)

def run(self):
 ##QObject.connect(self.loginQDialog, ? , ?)

def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.reject()